# Intellij restore deleted file (new file not in version control yet)

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I deleted a file in InteliJ and want to restore it.

What I tried:

- `Edit -> Undo` won't help here because I had to many actions after my mistake of deleting the wrong file
- `File -> LocalHistory` does not show my change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My mistake was to select `File`.

You have to navigate in `Project` to the folder or base project folder where the file was deleted from.

`Projects. Click on the folder -> Local History -> Select change and Revert`

[image: click path in intellij]

Now the file is recreated.